# Trying to SetFocus Based on If Criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a form where two employees will scan their badges when performing a certain task.  What I am trying to do is make sure that both employees scan their badges and that one employee cannot scan his badge twice.  A way to drive accountability if you will.  I have a picture of a bar code which equals "OK" that the user will scan when the message box appears (just in case there was a question).  Everything else works fine - I just cannot get the focus to go back to "Badge2" when Badge2 = "".

Code:

```
Private Sub Badge2_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Badge2.Value = Me.Badge.Value Then
Me.Badge2.Value = ""
MsgBox "You Must Scan Another Employee's Badge to Confirm Result! Scan OK to Scan Another Employee's Badge."
End If

If Me.Badge2.Value = "" Then
Me.Badge2.SetFocus
Else
Me.EID2.Value = DLookup("EID", "EmployeeID", "BADGENUMBER = form.Badge2")
Me.Employee2.Value = DLookup("Name", "EmployeeID", "BADGENUMBER = form.Badge2")

Sleep 2000

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the jumbled code before HansUp.  Still trying to get accustomed to formatting here.  I believe what you wrote was right on the money, but I just needed to put in the `Me.Badge2.Undo` function and then the `Cancel = True` function to maintain focus on the `Badge2`.  Thanks for putting up with my sloppiness and always helping.

Code:

```
Private Sub Badge2_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.Badge2.Value = Me.Badge.Value Then
    Me.Badge2.Undo
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "You Must Scan Another Employee's Badge to Confirm Result! Scan OK to Scan Another Employee's Badge."

Else
    Me.EID2.Value = DLookup("EID", "EmployeeID", "BADGENUMBER = form.Badge2")
    Me.Employee2.Value = DLookup("Name", "EmployeeID", "BADGENUMBER = form.Badge2")

    Sleep 2000

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Badge2_BeforeUpdate` event instead of `Badge2_AfterUpdate`.  When `Badge2.Value` does not satisfy your criteria, `Cancel` the update and focus will remain on `Badge2`.

Here is an abbreviated sample.  Refine it to add in the rest of the functionality you need.

```vb
Private Sub Badge2_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.Badge2.Value = Me.Badge.Value Or Me.Badge2.Value = "" Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```